# MongoDB “empty” or NULL Date

Tags: mongodb

I will begin using MongoDB in a project and made the following observation:
 **‘Date’ must be a valid point in time, and cannot be NULL**.

With MongoDB, we **cannot store a NULL date**, so I am guessing that the best thing to do is to simply **exclude the date field** from our document.

For example, if I have a ‘car’ document and a field named ‘**date_sold**’.  If the car has not been sold yet, I simply **exclude this field** from the document.  Once the car sells, I can **add the 'date_sold' field**.

By doing the above, I am assuming that I can query records for cars sold or not sold.  Is this a recommended way to handle “empty” or null dates in MongoDB?

P.S.  My confusion stems from the fact that since SQL has a schema, date or datetime fields can be stored as NULL, but in MongoDB, a ‘Date’ field cannot be NULL and must be a valid point in time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Omitting the date field when there is no date to store works fine in MongoDB unlike a traditional SQL database where every record / document has to follow the same schema.

You can use [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) to test for a value in that field.

Answer (score 5):

MongoDB types are [BSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/)

If you go to `DATE` type there, you will read:

> BSON Date is a 64-bit integer that represents the number of
>   milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970). This results in a
>   representable date range of about 290 million years into the past and
>   future.

So, you need to give a "point on time" per data type definition itself.

Usually the Unix Epoch -> `Jan 1, 1970` is the one used as `null` in order to follow good practices on most database systems that handle with that kind of  dates (if you don't need to work with dates as old as those ones).

Remember also this point:

> BSON Date type is signed. Negative values represent dates before 1970.

So, you can also set a convention default value for your development, that is on the past just for this purpose. For example:

`Jan 1, 1900`

I Hope this clarifies to you.

> One Hint more: As usually `json` structures may be validated on different steps, I strongly reccomend to you to maintain the field, and use a convention value for representing `NULL` under your system.

Comment: Alejandro, before posting my message, like you, I was thinking of setting either some massively old or futuristic date as my "null" convention.  I know that this would work but it does seem somewhat 'hacky' to me because this means that all mongodb users have different convetions.  If I don't get some feedback from my "missing field" idea mentioned above, I will probably just end up trying it to see how that works.  Of course, this will involve a bunch of query testing just to make sure that I don't end up with unforeseen issues.  Thank you anyway for your response which I up-voted.

Comment: Thank you very much @CarolineBeltran. My background is a backend billing systems analyst, and then, in the type of interfaces they use, it's usual to use those conventions (that as you said, each one has one different convention).  As also you point, Ian's answer is great too, as it solves the "insert" issue easily :) sincere thanks for your feedback Caroline!! I also upvoted Ian's answer as I thinks is really helpful and will solve your issue!